# What is Solr collection equivalent in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, solr, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb concepts. I am trying to understand what is equivalent Solr collection in mongodb. I am trying to create a product catalog application. Every manufacturer can have their own set fields in product documents. For every manufacturer i wanted store product and related document in a separate collection. How can i achieve the same in mongodb?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of doing the same. I recently got certification in MongoDB and one of the discussions involved creating text indexes and then searching using those indexes. Essentially, Solr is no longer necessary.

Begin here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/